# appending and formatting multi dimensional arrays in python Numpy

Tags: python, arrays, function, numpy, multidimensional-array

I want to write a code that appends a value to the `order` multidimensional array. If the last column is `0` order `indx[-1:,1] (function for the last element in the first column)` the it will append `10000` to the second column as well as `1` on the first column (1, 10000). If the first column last element is `1` than it will append `2` in the first column and `20000` in the second column (2, 20000). How could i write such  code without the use of a for loop or list comprehensions.

```
import numpy as np

order = np.array([[     0,  38846],
                  [     1,  51599],
                  [     0,  51599],
                  [     1,  52598],
                  [     0, 290480],
                  [     1, 335368],
                  [     0, 335916]])
```

Expected Output

```
#if the last element on column 1 is 1
[[     0,  38846]
 [     1,  51599]
 [     0,  51599]
 [     1,  52598]
 [     0, 290480]
 [     1, 335368]
 [     0, 335916]
 [     2,  20000]]
#if the last element on column 1 is 0
[[     0  38846]
 [     1  51599]
 [     0  51599]
 [     1  52598]
 [     0 290480]
 [     1 335368]
 [     0 335916]
 [     1  10000]]
```

Comment: Write the necessary code with lists or what ever you know best, and wel'll suggest inprovements.  Get something working first and worry about fast later.

Comment: You can use `np.vstack` to add the desired row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def extend(order):
    if order[-1, 0] == 0:
        return np.concatenate([order, np.array([[1, 10000]])], axis=0)
    elif order [-1, 0] == 1:
        return np.concatenate([order, np.array([[2, 20000]])], axis=0)
```